# Why does the return statement outputs incorrect string/int formatting?

Tags: python-2.7, return

Why does this program's `return` statement outputs the answer with brackets and quotations marks?

Example output: `('The age of the oldest child is', 6)`

Though when I use the `print` statement instead of `return`, the formatting is correct?

Example output with print statement: `The age of the oldest child is 6`

```
def ageOfOldest():

    age_youngest = input("Enter the age of the youngest child: ")
    age_middle = input("Enter the age of the middle child: ")

    age_of_oldest = (age_middle - age_youngest) + age_middle
    return "The age of the oldest child is ", age_of_oldest


print ageOfOldest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're returning a tuple. Try returning a string instead.

```
return "The age of the oldest child is {}".format(age_of_oldest)
```

Comment: I never knew that a string combined with a variable produces a tuple... How is .format going to transform it into a string?

Comment: You aren't "combining" them, you're [creating a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) out of them. The `str.format()` method returns a string.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a beginner and had a slightly altered definition of a tuple. ;)